# How to get rid of the 1GB overhead of MyISAM table without locking too much the system

Tags: mysql, optimization, myisam

I had some maintenance task completed on one of the tables, and now it has 1GB of overhead.

Since the table operations run for hours (delete 40% of records, took 4 hours) I do not want to lock the database with the OPTIMIZE table command for hours, so I am looking for alternatives how to deal with this overhead and remove with best method.

The table itself is 3GB, having 204 705 records.

Comment: Why do you want to? 1Gb is just not enough to be worth worrying about. I doubt rebuilding the table will improve performance much, just save a tiny amount of immensely cheap disc space (I am assuming that you do not have 10,000 such tables here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get around this problem by a 6 minute process doing the following:

```
CREATE TABLE table_reduced LIKE table;
ALTER TABLE table_reduced DISABLE KEYS;

insert into table_reduced
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    table;

ALTER TABLE table_reduced ENABLE KEYS;

RENAME TABLE table TO table_old;
RENAME TABLE table_reduced TO table;

DROP TABLE `table_old`;
```

Comment: ```RENAME TABLE `table` TO `table_old`, `table_reduced` TO `table`;``` would perform an atomic rename with no chance of raising a table not found error.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your table has no triggers on it, one easy way to accomplish an online OPTIMIZE is to use [pt-online-schema-change](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-online-schema-change.html) to rebuild the table. Since you said this is a MyISAM table you can just set the engine to MyISAM to accomplish a rebuild without changing anything:

```
pt-online-schema-change --alter "ENGINE=MyISAM" D=your_schema,t=your_table
```